# How do I serialize this twitter entity response from the stream api?

Tags: c#, serialization, twitter

This JSON response from the Twitter Stream API looks like so:

```
"entities": {
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 76360760611180544,
      "id_str": "76360760611180544",
      "media_url": "http://p.twimg.com/AQ9JtQsCEAA7dEN.jpg",
      "media_url_https": "https://p.twimg.com/AQ9JtQsCEAA7dEN.jpg",
      "url": "http://t.co/qbJx26r",
      "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/qbJx26r",
      "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/twitter/status/76360760606986241/photo/1",
      "sizes": {
        "large": {
          "w": 700,
```

**My class looks something like this:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Tweet {
    [DataMember]
    public entities entities;
}

[DataContract]
public class entities {
    [DataMember]
    public media media;
}
[DataContract]
public class media {
    [DataMember]
    public string id;
    [DataMember]
    public string id_str;
    [DataMember]
    public string media_url;
    [DataMember]
    public string media_url_https;
    [DataMember]
    public string url;
    [DataMember]
    public string display_url;
    [DataMember]
    public string expanded_url;
    [DataMember]
    public string type;
}
```

The problem I run into is that the media class is always null. Entities is not null when there is a picture attached to a tweet, but my media class remains null so I'm assuming I've written this incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In json square brackets holds arrays, therefore media should be a list.

http://www.secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

Comment: So something like this:  public media[] media;